# Using concurrent.futures.Future with greenlets/gevent

Tags: python, multithreading, concurrency, gevent

I have a python library that performs asynchronous network via multicast which may garner replies from other services. It hides the dirty work by returning a `Future` which will capture a reply. I am integrating this library into an existing gevent application. The call pattern is as simple as:

```
future = service.broadcast()
# next call blocks the current thread
reply = future.result(some_timeout)
```

Under the hood, `concurrent.futures.Future.result()` uses `threading.Condition.wait()`.

With a monkey-patched threading module, this seems fine and safe, and non-blocking with greenlets.

Is there any reason to be worried here or when mixing `gevent` and `concurrent.futures`?

Comment: fun we are seeing some mixing of python3's new native concurrency primitives and the old work-horse gevent (now that it works on python3.) glad to see below it seems to work for you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, as far as I can tell, `futures` isn't documented to work on top of `threading.Condition`, and `gevent` isn't documented to be able to patch `futures` safely. So, in *theory*, someone could write a Python implementation that would break `gevent`.

But in practice? It's hard to imagine what such an implementation would look like. You obviously need some kind of sync objects to make a `Future` work. Sure, you could use an `Event`, `Lock`, and `Rlock` instead of a `Condition`, but that won't cause a problem for `gevent`. The only way an implementation could plausibly break things would be to go directly to the pthreads/Win32/Java/.NET/whatever sync objects instead of using the wrappers in `threading`.

How would you deal with that if it happened? Well, `futures` is implemented in pure Python, and it's pretty simple Python, and there's a fully functional [backport](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/futures) that works with 2.5+/3.2+. So, you'd just have to grab that backport and swap out `concurrent.futures` for `futures`.

So, if you're doing something wacky like deploying a server that's going to run for 5 years unattended and may have its Python repeatedly upgraded underneath it, maybe I'd install the backport now and use that instead.

Otherwise, I'd just document the assumption (and the workaround in case it's ever broken) in the appropriate place, and then just use the stdlib module.

Comment: Indeed, after implementing and testing, everything works as advertised - or at least implied.

Comment: Condition is part of the gevent monkey patching.

https://github.com/gevent/gevent/blob/1.0.1/gevent/_threading.py#L89

Comment: @jhorman: Yes, and? The OP obviously already knew that, if you read the question.